# How does SGD come in the picture for Sequence to Sequence models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

I was learning that seq2seq models (from the deeplearning.ai course) try to maximize:

$$ \max_{y} P_{\theta}(y_1 \dots y_{T'} \mid x_1 \dots x_T ) $$

I learned that one way they do it is via beam search. However, what I don't understand is where SGD comes in the picture. I will explain the way I think it comes in the picture and the true objective I think we are trying to optimize. I think we are actually trying to optimize:

$$ \max_{\theta,y} P_{\theta}(y_1 \dots y_{T'} \mid x_1 \dots x_T ) = \max_{\theta,y} J(\theta,y) $$

we want to optimize the most likely sequence but we also want to improve the RNN parameters (or at least that's what I would have thought, specially since in normal supervised learning thats what we do).

So according to that I believe this is the way it would be done:

- at iteration $t$ we have model $\theta^{(t)}$
- we get it's most likely sequence with beam search $\hat y = y_1 \dots y_{T'} := BeamSearch(x_1...x_T,\theta^{(t)})$
- the using that most likely sequence we do SGD on the parameters according to the (normalized log likelihood) 
  $$\theta^{(t+1)} := \theta^{(t)} - \eta_t J(\theta^{(t)},\hat y)$$
  which basically makes the current most likely sequence even more likely with SGD
- repeat

I think this is probably wrong because it would seem this algorithm reinforces a specific sentence. If the first guess wasn't right I'd assume it would be some sort of horrible confirmation bias algorithm...but I can't see how SGD comes in the picture according to the descriptions I've read in Coursera's deeplearning.ai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence to sequence model produces a probability distribution over sequences $Y$ conditioned on another sequence $X$.

At test time, you may want to find the mode of that distribution: $\max_Y P(Y|X;\theta)$ -- the sequence which is most likely. For example if you have a translation model, you want to find the translation which has the highest probability under the model. This maximization must be done with beam search.

At training time, you already have $X,Y$ pairs from the data and you are simply trying to maximize the (log) likelihood of the model: $\max_\theta E[\log P(Y|X;\theta)]$. This is a completely different task from test time, and doesn't require beam search, and is done with SGD.

Comment: So beam search is only during test time?

Comment: @Pinocchio in this context -- yes